# Add Facebook Share button to static HTML page

Tags: html, facebook, share

Is there any way to add a Facebook **Share Button** to a static HTML page? I've implemented a simple web site with no server side, just a bunch of html pages and I was abble to add a Like button because it is implemented with iFrame element.
I have searched for a solution regarding the **Share Button** before posting here, but can't really find anything.

(Example of a share button can be seen on a youtube web site, on share section of each video.)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to generate your own button code here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: This page allows you to generate a like button which I was able to do. My problem is to get a Share Button which is different, it allows to users post a content from my page on their wall.

Comment: so you're looking to have people share it, not like it? Pass along parameters this way: http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com or whatnot - that'll scrape the page when you share your URL.

Comment: It works in quite a strange way, it removes completely all the styling of the box and shows big Facebook logo, also when you click it it shows share dialog in fullscreen page, not in popup. Could you please share whole code? And what do you mean by whatnot? Thanks

Comment: @Burjua the sharer.php link is just a bare link. there's no styled button involved. you would use it with standard HTML in an href tag. It just links you to a page on facebook that allows you to pass along 2 parameters about the page you're sharing: ?u=http://mylink.com&t=my+page+title - the title you specify only gets used if facebook can't scrape your page for more relevant info. most times, facebook will override what you put in the title parameter so it's almost easier to leave it out.

Answer (score 23):

This should solve your problem: [FB Share button/dialog documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/)
Genereally speaking you can use either normal HTML code and style it with CSS, or you can use Javascript.

Here is an example:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
    <img class="YOUR_FB_CSS_STYLING_CLASS" src="img/YOUR_FB_ICON_IMAGE.png" width="22px" height="22px" alt="Share on Facebook">
</a>
```

Replace **https%3A%2F%2Fparse.com**, **YOUR_FB_CSS_STYLING_CLASS** and **YOUR_FB_ICON_IMAGE.png** with your own choices and you should be ok.

**Note:** For the sake of your users' security use the HTTPS link to FB, like in the *a*'s *href* attribute.

Answer (score 4):

```
<a name='fb_share' type='button_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?appId={YOUR APP ID}&link=<?php the_permalink() ?>' rel='nofollow'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace `<url>` with your own link

```
<script>function fbs_click() {u=location.href;t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;}</script><style> html .fb_share_link { padding:2px 0 0 20px; height:16px; background:url(http://static.ak.facebook.com/images/share/facebook_share_icon.gif?6:26981) no-repeat top left; }</style><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fb_share_link">Share on Facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

In a very simple way, you can achieve this

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=your_page_link.com" target="_blank"> Facebook Share </a>
```

*replace `your_page_link.com` with your desired URL or page link

Example

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=youtube.com" target="_blank"> Facebook Share </a>
```

[image: img_Share]

Comment: This doesn’t open the link in the App

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div class="fb_share">
     <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="<?php the_permalink() ?>"
       href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Partilhar</a>
     <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script> </div> <?php }  }

 add_action('thesis_hook_byline_item','fb_share');
```